# Changing simulator language using iOS UiAutomation

Tags: ios, ios6, localization, ios-ui-automation

I am working on UIAutomation for an iOS app and the app is supported by multiple languages. So I wish to test the app in other languages as well.

I couldn't figure out as to how can I change the language in iPad/iPhone settings using iOS UiAutomation.

Has anybody came across this issue before? How do I change the language through settings or any iOS device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UI Automation for different languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364705/ios-ui-automation-for-different-languages)

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan has already replied to this kind of question before. it may be useful to check out the below stack overflow page:

[iOS UI Automation for different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364705/ios-ui-automation-for-different-languages)

There is Github sample project there which you can use for your ready reference.